# Leave remote graphical session open

Tags: ssh, vps, gnu-screen

I own a VPS with Ubuntu Server 14.04.

I know I can keep processes running using `screen`, but that's true only for non-graphical processes

How can I keep graphical processes alive (e.g. a browser) when I quit my ssh connection?

Comment: For web browsers, use a tunnel - https://calomel.org/firefox_ssh_proxy.html